# Determining cause of recurring external SSD data transfer with goal of preventing it

Tags: logs, disk, monitoring, io, logger

The LED lights for an external SSD connected via USB to a Linux Mint box indicate data transfer every 00:06:15 (6 mins 15 secs), despite no user applications (and possibly no processes) accessing the drive.  I've been trying to determine what is causing this recurring drive access.

The pattern of the LED lights indicate 2 consecutive (about 4 seconds apart) data transfers every 00:06:15 (6 minutes 15 seconds).

What I've done so far:

1. Tried to determine if it could be a weird hardware issue.  I temporarily connected the external SSD to a powered USB hub that was not attached to any computer. Because it was a powered USB hub, the SSD still received power.  The SSD's LED lights indicated incoming power, but never indicated data transfer every 00:06:15.
2. Created an exclusion in `timeshift` for the SSD's mount point.
3. Ran `gnome-system-monitor` with the `All processes` option enabled to see if it detected any correlated disk reads/writes.  It did not.
4. Ran `fatrace` to see if it detected any correlated file operations. It did not.  Although `fatrace` initially appeared to be amazing, I ultimately was let down by it.  After not detecting anything relevant, I opened `geany` (text editor) and wrote a file to the SSD.  `fatrace` did not detect the write operation.  I had to close `fatrace` and then reopen it to get it to detect the disk I/O operations performed by `geany`.  Thus, I'm not confident of the reliability of `fatrace` (or perhaps my understanding of it).
5. Installed `iotop`. Upon running `iotop`, it issued a message referencing `iotop` and a CVE.  I did not fully understand all the implications of that message, so I uninstalled `iotop`.
6. Ran `journalctl` to see if the journal logs revealed anything at the same time as the disk I/O.  They did not.
7. Determined if the issue persists when all Linux Mint users are logged out.  Interestingly, the issue still persisted.  I don't know exactly what this reveals, and am interested in feedback from others.

The only processes that I have seen correlated at all are, according to `fatrace`, ***sometimes*** `udisksd` and/or `systemd-udevd` access the root of the system drive (not the external SSD in question) around the same time.  But these correlations are inconsistent in that they sometime are non-existent and when they do exist, the timings are sometimes off by as much as a minute.  Thus, these apparent correlations may be nothing more than coincidences.

How can I determine what is causing this recurrent drive activity, with the ultimate goal of making it stop?

Comment: "I did not fully understand all the implications of that message" ... it's asking you to run it as root, or use `sudo`. The [CVE mentioned](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2011-2494) is for the kernel - unprivileged users can get sensitive information using the same method that `iotop` uses, so that method is no longer allowed to non-root users.

Comment: @muru Thanks. I think your rewording of that message adds some clarity for me.  Is there any harm/risk in running `iotop` or `iotop-c` as root or with `sudo`?

Comment: As with everything, there might be bugs, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you run fatrace correctly, though? `fatrace -t -f 'WD<>+'` is what I'm using and I've not missed a single file ever. This is strictly for changing/writing data, it ignores reads. If something is reading off your SSD, run it without any parameters.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks Artem.  Yes, I ran it with just `-t` to capture everything and show standard (non-epoch) timestamps.